# Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126 Please make sure cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll is in your library path a

Tags: python

I want to train the model to recognize various techniques, I make a model in darknet yolov4, put it on Windows 10, did everything, and VS 2019 put, and CMake, OpenCV, Cuda and CUDNN. Put Cuda and CUDNN in the environment variables and in the Path. As a result, when I'm going to put a model for training, this error appears[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvwAf.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me on yolov4. Somehow, cuddn 8.30 is not compatible. I installed **cudnn 8.2.2** and my problem was solved.

```
cudnn-11.4-windows-x64-v8.2.2.26
```

Download it from the Nvidia developer website.